# Targeting specific pages in the loop

Tags: wp-query, pages, conditional-tags

I am having a custom query that calls in pages in an array like so:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post__in' => array( 2, 7, 9, 11, 13 , 15, 17 ),
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
?>
```

Is it still possible to target single pages of the array to have page specific alterations of the code, i.e.

```
<?php if(is_page(7)) { ?>
    // do something
<?php } else { ?>
    // do something else
<?php } ?>
```

inside this query or do I have to query every page in a a separate query?

I am using this query to put together multiple pages into one template (front-page.php) in order to have a onepaged layout, i.e. all content on one page, so I would like to use conditions inside the loop for clarity in my code.

Comment: Do you want to target specific posts by modifying/adding code to your custom loop code or you're happy to use a custom function?

Comment: I use that query to combine the content of multiple pages into one (front-page.php), so I can have a onepaged layout. Thus for clarity I would like to use conditions inside my template file (front-page.php) rather than catering conditions inside the functions.php :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would rather want to use the post ID inside the loop to target your pages. `is_page()` simply checks whether the current page is actually a page or a specific page if a value is passed

### Example

```
if ( $post->ID === 7 ) {
    // Do something for page id 7
} else {
    // Do something for other pages
}
```

Comment: Why not use if ( is_single( '7' ) ) {

Comment: My solution relates to use of code in a custom function. Not sure he specifically wants a solution which is added to his custom loop code.

Comment: I yes, I completely missthought the use of conditional tags for pages which I use so often - of course I cannot use it here, since the actual page I am on is clearly some other page (front-page.php in my case), so it does not work through my conditions. However, the example you provided causes a 500 error on my testing site ($post->ID === 7), even though it seems like it is right to me..

Comment: What happens when you do `var_dump( $post->ID );` inside the loop. Cannot see why you get a 500 error

Comment: For some reason, both fail and give out my 500 error. Edit: it returns 'int(11)', while the 11 is the page ID.

Comment: That is totally strange why you get the 500 error. Something is really strange on your local install. Turn debugging on and see what errors you get

Comment: Oh my, it must be something else, your answer is 100% correct, but seemed to have trigged some kind of eternal loop I miscreated on some repeater custom field inside one of my conditions. My bad, thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. I hope you get your 500 error solved. Good luck :-)

Comment: It was a missing (), no more than that - thanks again & until next time :).